# Finding interaction between several factors and multiple dependent variables

Tags: anova, manova

Asking a question essentially for a colleague, since it's far enough afield of what I do that I want to make sure I don't lead her astray:

Assume a study with 5 factors and 3 dependent variables - we'd like to test the effect of interaction between any two factors on a given dependent variable (for Factor A at some level and Factor B at some level increases the mean of dependent variable A).

Should this be handled with two-way ANOVA or MANOVA? My instinct is to say MANOVA unless there's reason to believe there's no correlation between any of the dependent variables, but I figured it's best to run it by folks who do that more than I do.